# How to change vpn ip on timeout - Vpn rotator script

Tags: python, security, vpn

I want to write a script that will change a vpn ip depending on ping. For example when I continuously ping "google.com" and it receives timeout it should immediately changes the vpn ip to another ip (openvpn). The neccessary configs are stored in a folder.
How can I make this current script rotate the vpns on timeouts?

```
 import os
import numpy as np
hostname = "google.com" 
def reconnect_vpn():
    all_files = os.listdir(path)
    while True:
        entry_nr = np.randint(len(all_files))
        file = all_files[entry_nr]
        if file.split('.')[1] == 'ovpn':
            break
    os.system('openvpn '+file)


while True:
    response = os.system("ping -c 1" + hostname)

    #and then check the response...
    if response == 0:
      continue;
    else:
      reconnect_vpn()
```

Comment: try to be more specific in your question so people can help you. What is your specific question?

Comment: how to make this current script rotate the vpns on timeouts.